# Why does my code not write the data it receives from the build_info function to the json file?

Tags: python, json, mongodb, pymongo, shodan

```py
api = shodan.Shodan(api_key)

query = 'MongoDB Server Information \n{ "process": "mongod" port:27017'

build_info_arr = []

try:
    results = api.search(query)
    print('Total Results: %s\n' % results['total'])

    for result in results['matches']:
        if "Authentication partially enabled" not in result['data']:
            print('IP: {}'.format(result['ip_str']))
            ip: str = format(result['ip_str'])
            collections = mongodb_search.build_info(ip)

            if collections:
                data = json.loads(collections)
                for build_infos in data.items():
                    build_info_arr.append(build_infos)

except shodan.APIError as e:
    print('Error: {}'.format(e))

with open('./test.json', "wt") as jsonfile:
    jsonfile.write(json.dumps(build_info_arr, indent=4, sort_keys=False))
```

My build_info function is here:

```py
def build_info(ip):
    try:
        client = pymongo.MongoClient(ip, 27017, maxPoolSize=10)
        data = ''
        for build_info in client.db.command({'buildInfo': 1}):
            data += str(json.dumps(build_info))
            file = json.loads(data)
            return file
    except:
        print('Error: Cannot retrieve buildinfo.')
```

Comment: So, what *do* you get in your file and what were you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json.dump()` instead of `json.dumps()` to writes the file directly, try changing to this:

```
with open('./test.json', "w") as jsonfile:
    json.dump(build_info_arr, jsonfile, indent=4, sort_keys=False)
```

Comment: I get this error: "json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value:"

Comment: sorry i had a typo

Answer (score 0):

Not directly related to your question but a few things:

1. Shodan already collects that information and stores it in the `mongodb.buildInfo` property: https://datapedia.shodan.io/property/mongodb.html
2. You can use a search query of "product:mongodb" which is shorter and takes advantage of our fingerprinting so you can find services on non-standard ports.
3. Use the `Shodan.search_cursor(query)` method to iterate over results. It handles paging for you. See: https://help.shodan.io/guides/how-to-download-data-with-api